# The etiquette of finding web services?

Tags: web-services

This is an unusual question. I am learning about web services and using SOAP protocol.

I wanted to make an small application to test my knowledge but how do you find web services and how do you know which companies provide them? For example, let's I wanted to write code that tells me all the McDonald restaurants in a given town. How do I know if McDonald provides a web service that gives store info?

Am I correct to assume that the majority of companies provide a web service?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called a uddi registry. They exist within enterprises if at all these days.

The equivalent on the internet today is http://www.programmableweb.com

Comment: "They exist within enterprises if at all these days." - could you please elaborate what you meant by this?

Comment: In the height of service oriented architecture 5-10 years ago there was a plan that all web services would be described and published inside a UDDI either within an enterprise or publicly. That never picked up as much as expected

Answer (score 0):

Some services are public, others not, some need authentication, others not, and more. All these details are provided by companies, if they want to do. To know if MacDonalds provide services you need to google about it, search in their website or you can contact they asking for it.